# Union with pointer to array

Tags: c++, unions

In C++ I want to declare an array of pointers that are either `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`, depending on some input. So it would like either

```
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[N];
```

or

```
unsigned short *data = new unsigned short[N];
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is it an option two maintain two arrays and work with a pointer that will then be casted to the coresponding type?

Comment: _"What's the best way to go about this?"_ make it a template.

Comment: How about allocating per input type, and always casting down to `unsigned char*`, and then go about reading values from that array based on the input (cast to `short` later if necessary)

Comment: You want array of pointers or array of unsigned chars/shorts? Your description is in conflict with code

Answer (score 3):

> *"What's the best way to go about this?"*

Make the context templated, e.g.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct MyStuff {
    std::array<T,N> data;
}
```

or

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct MyStuff {
    std::vector<T> data;

    MyStuff() {
        data.resize(N);
    }
}
```

if you really need dynamic allocation